# HealthKit data size limitation for WatchKit?

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit

Is there a limit to the amount of data that can be gathered for `HealthKit`?

For example, I want to keep the heart beat collection to `HealthKit` for 8 hours continuously before being able to connect to a phone.

Is there a limitation on the amount of data being collected before "**syncing**" up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a limit. HealthKit will keep recording the user's heart rate samples on Apple Watch regardless of whether it has been able to sync with the paired iPhone.

Do note that HealthKit on watchOS only stores data that is at most about a week old.